# How to style WP Contact Form 7 Plugin Form using Bootstrap and Own stylesheet?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form-7

I my website I am using WordPress Contact Form 7 to get some information from my users. The website is built using Bootstrap Framework.

Now I want to use my custom css style and Bootstrap style to the form.  So that I am using following code. But Its not styling.

Anybody tell me how can I style this form ?

**Here what I am using in the contact form 7**

```
<h3>Which Goal You Are Looking To Achieved ?</h3>

<div class="asking-box">

    <h4><strong>Select your Goals</strong></h4>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="question">Lasting happiness </label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            [checkbox checkbox-959 class:"my-check"]
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="question">Lasting happiness </label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            [checkbox* checkbox-404 class:my-check]
        </div>
     </div>


   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ad this link in your header

```
 <link href="/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and this is in your page

```
 <div class="register-box">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="inner-srch-pg">
                <div class="bnr-srch-box">
                   <form action=""  method="post" >
                      <div class="rgstr-form-cntnt">
                        <div class="row">
                         <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="286" title="Contact form 1"]'); ?>
                         </div>
                         </div>
                   </form>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can now achieve this much more easily by using this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) to design responsive grid-layouts for your cf7 forms.